# Regular expression to include starting string

Tags: c#, regex

I have managed to match into groups as follows using the below expression but its incomplete.

`\([^\)]*\)`

Example strings are,

s11(h 1 1 c)(h 1 1 c) x="" y="" z="" phi="" theta=""

e(45,10,h 1 1 c,1,cross,max) x="" y="" z="" phi="" theta=""

With the above expression I can match `(h 1 1 c)(h 1 1 c)` and `(45,10,h 1 1 c,1,cross,max)`

But I want to capture the starting string `s11` and `e` along with `(h 1 1 c)(h 1 1 c)` and `(45,10,h 1 1 c,1,cross,max)`

Comment: Try `\w+(?:\([^()]*\))+` if there can be no nested parentheses.

Comment: `(\w+)(\([^()]*\)){1,2}` has two groups that match the result to want to capture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
var lines = new List<string> { "s11(h 1 1 c)(h 1 1 c) x=\"\" y=\"\" z=\"\" phi=\"\" theta=\"\"",
"e(45,10,h 1 1 c,1,cross,max) x=\"\" y=\"\" z=\"\" phi=\"\" theta=\"\""};
foreach (var s in lines)
{
    Console.WriteLine("==== Next string: \"" + s + "\" =>");
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ",
            Regex.Matches(s, @"\w+(?:\([^()]*\))+").Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Value)));
            
    Console.WriteLine("=== With groups and captures:");
    var results = Regex.Matches(s, @"(\w+)(?:(\([^()]*\)))+");
    foreach (Match m in results)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", m.Groups[2].Captures.Cast<Capture>().Select(z => z.Value)));
    }
}
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/HsLepC). Output:

```cs
==== Next string: "s11(h 1 1 c)(h 1 1 c) x="" y="" z="" phi="" theta=""" =>
s11(h 1 1 c)(h 1 1 c)
=== With groups and captures:
s11
(h 1 1 c), (h 1 1 c)
==== Next string: "e(45,10,h 1 1 c,1,cross,max) x="" y="" z="" phi="" theta=""" =>
e(45,10,h 1 1 c,1,cross,max)
=== With groups and captures:
e
(45,10,h 1 1 c,1,cross,max)
```

Depending on what exact results you want to get, you may use a regex with or without capturing groups:

```cs
\w+(?:\([^()]*\))+
(\w+)(?:(\([^()]*\)))+
```

See the [regex 1 demo](http://%5Cw+(?:%5C(%5B%5E()%5D*%5C))%20) and [regex 2 demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5Cw%2B%29%28%3F%3A%28%5C%28%5B%5E%28%29%5D*%5C%29%29%29%2B&i=s11%28h%201%201%20c%29%28h%201%201%20c%29%20x%3D%22%22%20y%3D%22%22%20z%3D%22%22%20phi%3D%22%22%20theta%3D%22%22%0D%0Ae%2845%2C10%2Ch%201%201%20c%2C1%2Ccross%2Cmax%29%20x%3D%22%22%20y%3D%22%22%20z%3D%22%22%20phi%3D%22%22%20theta%3D%22%22).

**Details**

- `\w+` - one or more word chars (letters, digits and some connector puncutation)
- `(?:\([^()]*\))+` - one or more repetitions of

  - `\(` - a `(` char
  - `[^()]*`  - zero or more chars other than `(` and `)`
- `\)` - a `)` char.

Comment: Your first expression worked. I never managed to learn them properly. Once I understand they look simple and yet powerful.